# Matlab) what should I put more with function for, sttrep, cell?

Tags: matlab

### I want to make the results like this:

> > phraseblanks

phrasemat = Hello and how are you?

Hi there everyone!

How is it going?

WHazzup?

Phrase 1 had 4 blanks

Phrase 2 had 3 blanks

Phrase 3 had 2 blanks

Phrase 4 had 0 blanks

New phrasemat is :

Hello&and&how&are&you?

Hi&there&everyone!

How&is&it&going?

WHazzup?

---

so I made script **"phraseblanks.m"**:

```
phrasemat = char('Hello and how are you?', ...
                 'Hi there everyone!', 'How is it going?', 'WHazzup?')

[r, c] = size(phrasemat);

for i = 1:r

    phrasemat_new = cell(r, c);
    howmany = countblanks(phrasemat(i, :));
    fprintf('Phrase %d had %d blanks\n', i, howmany);
    phrasemat(i,:) = strrep(phrasemat(i,:),' ','&')
    phrasemat_new{i,:} = [phrasemat(i,:)];

end

fprintf('Changing one is %s\n', eval('phrasemat_new'));
```

script **"countblanks.m"**:

```
function num = countblanks(phrase)    
   % countblanks returns the # of blanks in a trimmed string    
   % Format: countblanks(string)

   num = length(strfind(strtrim(phrase), ' '));

end
```

and I keep having errors.

please help me..

Comment: In `for` loop in phraseblanks.m, `j` is not initialized.

Comment: countblanks is not needed here. Try instead matlabs function `isspace`. `howmany = sum(isspace(phrasemat(i, :)))`. also `phrasemat(i,:) = strrep(phrasemat(i,:),' ','&');` could be replaced with `phrasemat(i,isspace(phrasemat(i,:))) = &;`

Answer (score 0):

I modified slightly your **phraseblanks.m** so that it works.

```
phrasemat = {'Hello and how are you?', ...
                 'Hi there everyone!', ...
                 'How is it going?', ...
                 'WHazzup?'};

r = numel(phrasemat);
phrasemat_new = cell(1, r);

for i = 1:r

    howmany = countblanks(phrasemat{i});   
    fprintf('Phrase %d had %d blanks\n', i, howmany);
    phrasemat{i} = strrep(phrasemat{i}, ' ', '&');    
    phrasemat_new(i) = phrasemat(i);

end

fprintf('Changing one is %s\n', phrasemat_new{:});
```

Obviously it could be written in a nicer, more "matlaby-way", but I didn't want to stride too far from your original version. Also you could consider using regular expressions, since if you have to spaces next to each other and you want to treat them as one blank space.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me
and I'm curious why the part of result is
phrasemat = 

    [1x22 char]    'Hi there everyone!'    'How is it going?'    'WHazzup?'

if the string is more than 21 characters, they can't show it?

Comment: @user3326452 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean , when I save the script as you wrote and 
input >> phraseblanks 

the result was 



phrasemat = 



    [1x22 char]    'Hi there everyone!'    'How is it going?'    'WHazzup?'

instead of  'Hello and how are you?'   ''Hi there everyone!'    'How is it going?'    'WHazzup?'